# Proof of equivalence of commutativity of flows and [X,Y]=0

Tags: differential-geometry, classical-mechanics

I am reading through the proof of the following theorem:
[image]
[image]
The proof follows the the proof which can be found in Arnold's book about Classical mechanics.

**What I don't understand is in the following part of the proof:**
[image]
**Question** What is $O(s^2 t,st^2)$? Shouldn't it be $O(s^2+t^2)$, since we have a Taylor expansion of order two?

**Attempt of an answer**

- I think from Corollary C.16 (below) we have that it follows that
  $|\Delta(s,t,x)-T_{2}|\in O(||(s,t)||^{3})$. Going back to the definition of $O$ I get
  $|\Delta(s,t)-T_{2}|\leq M|(s^2+t^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}|\leq|(s^2+t^2)^{3}|=M|s^3+3ts^2+3st^2+t^3|\leq M|3ts^2+3st^2|=3M|ts^2+st^2|$. Hence, $\Delta(s,t)-T_{2}\in O(st^2,ts^2)\iff \Delta(s,t)=T_{2}+O(st^2,ts^2)$

[image]

- **To show that** $\Delta(s,t)=st\frac{\partial^{2}\Delta}{\partial s\partial t}|_{(0,0)}+O(st^2,ts^2)$, I would go back to the definition of the partial derivative. Then I would say the fact that $\Delta(0,t,x)=\Delta(s,0,x)=0$ implies that both $\frac{\partial\Delta}{\partial s}(0,0)=0$ and $\frac{\partial\Delta}{\partial t}(0,0)=0$. Therefore $\frac{\partial^{2} \Delta}{\partial s^{2}}(0,0)=\frac{\partial^{2}\Delta}{\partial t^{2}}(0,0)=0$.
  For the mixed term I get $\frac{\partial^{2}\Delta}{\partial  s\partial t} (0,0):=\lim_{h_{1},h_{2}\to 0}\frac{\Delta(h_{1},h_{2})}{h_{1}h_{2}}$. Of course having in mind that itterated limits are not necessarily the same. But since $\Delta$ is cont. partially differentiable, I guess it is okay.

Comment: $O$ is not $o$.

Answer (score -1):

The largest terms of the error term, $O(s^2 t,st^2)$, come from the cube, $(s+t)^3$. The reason that $s^3$ and $t^3$ are omitted is that they will always vanish under the limit. This is not true in general for the middle terms (recall from multivariable calculus that convergence to a point for 2 (or more) independent variables can sometimes work for some trajectories, but not others; directional limits may not agree or not even exist for all trajectories, even when some do exist).

Comment: I am afraid I am not entirely sure what you mean.

Comment: Are you familiar with Big-O notation? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

Comment: Smooth implies $\mathcal{C}^k$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Smooth means that all of the derivatives (of any order) are continuous and differentiable. The reason for the non-vanishing error term is related to the fact that the existence of all directional derivatives and continuity is not sufficient to guarantee that a function of several variables is differentiable at that point, see the example here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_in_higher_dimensions)

Comment: Sorry I was still writing. Yes. I think the confusion comes from the fact that my analysis books assume $f$ to be $\mathcal{C}^k$, but since $f$ is smooth we have a remainder which is $O$, which follows from some estimate of the remainder term. However, I am still not too happy about why $O(|(s,t)|^3)=O(st^2,ts^2)$ and why is it not enough to now that we have some $O(|(s,t)|^3)$?

Comment: The reason you don't see $O(s^3 ,s^2 t ,st^2, t^3)$ is because they note that the $s^3$ and $t^3$ terms vanish because $\Delta (t,0,x)=\Delta (0,s,x)=0$. So the contribution of those terms will *always* be $0$.

Comment: Would that find that if I looked at the 3rd order expansion? And then realise that all terms after $\frac{1}{2}(t^2....)$ is a function that can be viewed as depending on $st^2$ and $ts^2$,i.e. f(st^2,ts^2) and $f\in O(st^2,ts^2)$?

Comment: I am not sure you fully understand what is meant by Big-O notation in this context, see the subsection in the wikipedia link above titled infinitesimal asymptotics. That section describes the kind of usage that is being done here (though the examples given there are for a single variable). In effect, what you have here is that, in a small enough neighborhood of $(0,0)$, there are constants, $a$ and $b$, so that all the terms beyond the quadratic expansion (3rd term and beyond of Taylor expansion), can be bounded by $a s^2 t+bst^2$.

Comment: Okay, but isn't that what I meant? Why exactly does $\Delta(t,0,x)=\Delta(0,s,x)=0$ imply the last equality in the proof? I tried to make sense of it by looking at the definition of partial derivatives. I guess I am mistaken, but don't they all vanish? How do I end up with the term $st\frac{\partial\Delta^{2}}{\partial s\partial t}\neq 0$?

Comment: The higher order terms do not vanish in general, but that is not the point. What this argument does is it looks at the infinitesimal action of the Lie Bracket on a function $F$. By looking at the Taylor expansion of this action, they can show that if the flows $\Phi_t$ and $\Psi_s$ commute, then the remaining terms *will* all be $0$, thus proving the necessity of the Lie bracket vanishing when the flows commute (it is, in fact, both necessary and sufficient, i.e. a characterization of what it means for the flows to commute).

Comment: Sorry, but I have a really hard time following your arguments. Now I am more confused than before. In the 5th comment from the top you say that the $s^3$ and $t^3$ terms vanish because of $\Delta(0,s,x)=\Delta(t,0,x)=0$.  I think I figured out why the mixed terms is not zero.